# Create a keyword in python instead of inheriting from a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, keyword

Is it possible to create a keyword in python that's equivalent to inheriting a class?

So given class:

```
class Hello:
  pass
```

I could write

```
keyword Custom:
 pass
```

which would be equivalent to

```
class Custom(Hello):
  pass
```

Comment: As far as I know, you can't, you can't monkey patch `class`  which is a reserved keyword.

Comment: You should ask what is the point in the first place? I.e. this may be XY problem.

Comment: Is it technically possible? Well, if you're willing to accept certain conditions, like needing your own Python fork and your code not being compatible with standard Python, yes. Should you do it? 99.9999% of the time: no.